# WPF C# String Format

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho um usercontrol com a seguinte configuração:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PainelPendencias.View.PendenciaConsulta"
             x:Name="uCPendenciaConsulta"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xml:lang="pt-BR"
             d:DesignHeight="720"  d:DesignWidth="1024">
```

Em uma coluna do DataGrid faço o stringformat abaixo:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Binding="{Binding OperacaoValor, StringFormat=N}" IsReadOnly="True">
```

O valor recebido a ser formatado é: 100543.67M.

O problema é que em algumas máquinas está sendo mostrado corretamente: 100.543,67 e em outras está adicionando zeros: 10.054.367,00.

[Atualização] Na máquina que está com formato incorreto fui nas configurações regionais e removi a adição de 2 casas decimais [paliativo]. Porém nas máquinas que funcionam esta adição existe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou outros meios de formatação de número? Veja mais outros exemplos.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Binding="{Binding OperacaoValor, StringFormat={}{0:#,#.00}}" IsReadOnly="True">
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Binding="{Binding OperacaoValor, StringFormat={0:#,0} {1:#,0}}" IsReadOnly="True">
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Binding="{Binding OperacaoValor, StringFormat=\{0:N0\}}" IsReadOnly="True">
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Binding="{Binding OperacaoValor, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" IsReadOnly="True">
```

**Atualização da resposta**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Binding="{Binding OperacaoValor, StringFormat='#,##0.00', ConverterCulture='pt-BR'}" IsReadOnly="True">
```

Comment: Os 2 primeiros não são compilados, recebo a seguinte mensagem: "O tipo '' não foi encontrado. Verifique se não há uma referência de assembly ausente e se todos os assemblies referenciados foram criados.".

Os dois últimos estão formatando assim "2.065.000" um valor que era pra estar assim "2.065.000,00".

O valor que passei na pergunta está saindo assim: 100.544

Comment: @Denis atualizei a resposta, veja se este formato + forçar a cultura para pt-BR fique da forma requisitada - com _ponto_ para milhar e _vírgula_ para decimal.

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu Ismael!!

Answer (score 1):

Tente ConverterCulture=pt-BR assim:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Binding="{Binding OperacaoValor, ConverterCulture=pt-BR}" IsReadOnly="True">
```